How to get typed data from sql select statement to Excel
ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application controller should create an Excel spreadsheet with typed data in columns (numbers, strings, dates, logical) from arbitrary SQL select.
I tried this code:
public async Task<IActionResult> RawData() 
{
    // https://blog.elmah.io/export-data-to-excel-with-asp-net-core/
    using var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
    using IDataReader dr = ExecuteReader("select * from foo", out IDbConnection _);

    int currentRow= 1 ;

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < dr.FieldCount; j++)
            if (dr.GetFieldType(j) != typeof(byte[]))
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, j + 1).Value = dr.GetValue(j).ToString();

        currentRow++;
    }

    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    workbook.SaveAs(stream);
    var content = stream.ToArray();

    return File(content, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "test.xlsx");
}

Numeric, double, float, integer, boolean appear as strings in Excel.
Removing ToString() using
worksheet.Cell(currentRow, j + 1).Value = dr.GetValue(j);

throws a compile error.
How to get typed data from IDataReader into Excel or ods file?
Application uses Entity Framework Core. Maybe datareader can be replaced with Database.FromSQLRawAsync() and dynamic used.

ClosedXML requires XLCellValue for cell values. There is factory method which creates appropriate XLCellValue from object
worksheet.Cell(currentRow, j + 1).Value = XLCellValue.FromObject(dr.GetValue(j));

